# Download Manager Pro issue - Video File Corrupt After Download Complete

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using [Download Manager Pro](https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro)

Everthing was good but now having some problem when i download completes.

**The problem is with os lolipop and higher**

**issue:**
whenever i start downloads and once i switch off and switch on internet connection of device then after video is successfully resume downloading but after download completes that file is getting corrupted.

**Note:** Problem is with video files only, because downloaded mp3 files does not have this issue.

Is anyone used this please help :(
Please give a solution or suggestion if someone ever did this 
Thanks in advance.